# What is underneath the original bath tile in my 1950s home?

Tags: bathroom, flooring

My home is a pier and beam 1950s home.

I recently had a water leak and it damaged the flooring in my bathroom. I pulled it up, and it turns out there are several layers of flooring, all of which have some amount of water damage.

At the bottom (or what I hope is the bottom) is the original tile floor. I started pulling up some tiles that were loose from what I think is previous water damage, and found what looks like a dirt floor.

[image]

Here is a closer view of where I've removed loose tiles

[image]

I thought it might just be a crushed layer of thinset, so I tried to break through it and it just seems to keep going! I grabbed a masonry bit and drilled down ~5" before I ran out of bit.

[image]

Any thoughts in what this is and how I would go about fixing this floor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is likely a mud bed/mortar bed which was what was used before thinset and cement board became the standard, basically a dry pack of sand and cement lightly wetted and screed flat.

https://www.tcnatile.com/faqs/71-thick-setthick-bed.html